# selenium export file options php missing

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium for my php applicaiton, I am using php script to test, I am unable to find the option in file export file as php, I get java and other etc. Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks a lot 
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP export function has been removed (from version 1.2 onwards I think) as it was no longer part of the supported languages. A [seperate add-in](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/) has been created to put the functionality back into the IDE: install that one, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could use sauce lab's selenium builder . It is pretty easy to use and u can export the file in php .